# Actualizar datos en BD y volverlos a mostrar en recyclerview

Tags: android, json, android-sqlite, android-volley

Saludos este es mi primer post y el problema que tengo es que estoy haciendo una aplicación en la cual almaceno imágenes en un `webservice` y como respuesta obtengo un `array` con los nombre de las imágenes que fueron almacenadas, este lo proceso y actualizo el campo `Sync` en la `BD` para indicar que esa imagen ya fue enviada, todo esto función bien, el problema es cuando quiero actualizar mi `recyclerview` para que muestre un `Check` indicando que la imagen ya fue enviada este no lo hace.

Por depuración me di cuenta que el problema es que los datos si son actualizados en la `BD` pero cuando se realiza el llenado del cursor este continua teniendo los mismos datos y no los nuevos a pesar de que cierro el cursor, la `BD` y la conexión.

Para ver los cambios tengo que cerrar la actividad donde se están mostrando las imágenes y volverla abrir.

Estaré haciendo algo mal su ayuda por favor.

Esta es la función con la cual envió las imágenes y actualizo el campo `Sync` en la `BD`

```
    private void crearObjetoJson() {
    try {
        jsonArray = new JSONArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < listSeleccion.size(); i++) {
            objetoFotos = new JSONObject();
            objetoFotos.put("NOM_FOTOGRAFIA", listSeleccion.get(i).getNombreFoto());

            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(listSeleccion.get(i).getUbicacion());
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,stream);
            byte[] array = stream.toByteArray();
            String foto_codificada = Base64.encodeToString(array,Base64.DEFAULT);

            objetoFotos.put("IMAGEN",foto_codificada);


            jsonArray.put(objetoFotos);
        }
        //String array = jsonArray.toString();
        //System.out.println("jsonString: " + array);

    }catch (JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    JsonArrayRequest jsonRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_ENVIO_FOTOS, jsonArray,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    try {
                        Log.i("JsonArray",response.toString());
                        DBHelper conn = new DBHelper(Fotografias_Capturadas.this,DBHelper.DB_NAME,null,DBHelper.DB_VERSION);
                        SQLiteDatabase db = conn.getWritableDatabase();
                        db.beginTransaction();
                        for(int i=0;i<response.length();i++){
                            JSONObject jresponse = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            String nom_Fotografia = jresponse.getString("NOM_FOTOGRAFIA");

                            Log.i("NomFoto",nom_Fotografia);

                            String Query = "UPDATE FOTOGRAFIAS SET SYNCRONIZACION='1' WHERE NOM_FOTOGRAFIA ='" + nom_Fotografia + "'";
                            db.execSQL(Query);
                        }
                        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
                        db.endTransaction();
                        db.close();
                        conn.close();

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(Fotografias_Capturadas.this, error.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

    VolleySingleton.getInstanciaVolley(Fotografias_Capturadas.this).addToRequestQueue(jsonRequest);

}
```

Esta es la clase con la que cargo mis imágenes y las muestro en el `recycler`.

```
    private void cargar_imagenes() {
    DBHelper conn = new DBHelper(this,DBHelper.DB_NAME,null,DBHelper.DB_VERSION);
    SQLiteDatabase db = conn.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor =null;
    cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT CODIGO as _id, CODIGO_DEFECTO, CODIGO_CIRCUITO, NOM_FOTOGRAFIA, SYNCRONIZACION FROM FOTOGRAFIAS",null);

    DatosFotografias datos;
    listFotografias = new ArrayList<>();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()){
        datos = new DatosFotografias();
        datos.setCodigo(cursor.getString(0));
        datos.setCodigoDefecto(cursor.getString(1));
        datos.setCodigoSegmento(cursor.getString(2));
        datos.setNombreFoto(cursor.getString(3));
        datos.setUbicacion(RutaFotos + "/" + cursor.getString(3) + ".JPG");
        datos.setSync(cursor.getString(4));

        listFotografias.add(datos);
    }

    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    conn.close();

    adapter = new AdapterFotografias(this,listFotografias,this);
    recyclerFotos.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerFotos.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
}
```

Adaptador

```
    public class AdapterFotografias extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterFotografias.ViewHolder> {
    Context context;
    ArrayList<DatosFotografias> listFotos;
    Fotografias_Capturadas activity;
    FrameLayout frameLayout;
    View view;
    int posicion;


public AdapterFotografias(Context context, ArrayList<DatosFotografias> listFotografias, Fotografias_Capturadas activity) {
    this.context = context;
    this.listFotos = listFotografias;
    this.activity =activity;
}

@Override
public AdapterFotografias.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.fotografias_item,parent,false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(AdapterFotografias.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    posicion=holder.getAdapterPosition();

    if (!activity.is_in_actionMode){
        holder.checkBoxFotos.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }else {
        holder.checkBoxFotos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }


    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(listFotos.get(position).getUbicacion()));

    Glide.with(context)
            .load(uri)
            .centerCrop()
            .placeholder(R.drawable.camara)
            .crossFade()
            .into(holder.imageFoto);

    holder.imageFoto.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);

    if (listFotos.get(position).getSync().equals("0")){
        holder.imageCheck.setImageResource(R.drawable.wait);
    }else{
        holder.imageCheck.setImageResource(R.drawable.check);
    }


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return (listFotos == null) ?0:listFotos.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    ImageView imageFoto, imageCheck;
    CheckBox checkBoxFotos;



    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        imageFoto = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ImagenFotoTotal);
        imageCheck = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ImagenCheckTotal);
        frameLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.frameLayout);
        checkBoxFotos = itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkboxFotos);
        imageFoto.setOnLongClickListener(activity);
        imageFoto.setOnClickListener(activity);
        checkBoxFotos.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        activity.prepararSeleccion(view,getAdapterPosition());
        activity.mostrarImagenSeleccionada(getAdapterPosition());
    }
}

public void removeAdapter(ArrayList<DatosFotografias> list){
    for (DatosFotografias fotografias : list){
        listFotos.remove(fotografias);
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

}

Comment: pon el código de tu adapter

Comment: @diegoveloper ya agregue mi adapter